# The problem of merging dataframes with different rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

When i have these 2 dataframes,,

```
df1:        df2:
col1 col2 | col3 col4
1    2    | 0    0
3    4    | 0    0
          | 0    0
```

I want to merge them into this form.

```
col1 col2  col3 col4
1    2     0    0
3    4     0    0
           0    0
```

If I use concat, this is what happens.
concat([df1,df2],axis=1)

```
col1 col2  col3 col4
1    2     0    0
3    4     0    0
0    0
```

Comment: What do you expect to be in the bottom row for columns `col1` and `col2`?

Answer (score 1):

The issue must be somewhere in your actual code, since this is what I get:

```
from pandas import DataFrame, concat

df1 = DataFrame([
    {'col1': 1., 'col2': 2.},
    {'col1': 3., 'col2': 4.}
])

df2 = DataFrame([
    {'col3': 5., 'col4': 6.},
    {'col3': 7., 'col4': 8.},
    {'col3': 9., 'col4': 0.}
])

print(df1)
print(df2)
print(concat([df1, df2], axis=1))
```

Result:

```
   col1  col2
0   1.0   2.0
1   3.0   4.0
   col3  col4
0   5.0   6.0
1   7.0   8.0
2   9.0   0.0
   col1  col2  col3  col4
0   1.0   2.0   5.0   6.0
1   3.0   4.0   7.0   8.0
2   NaN   NaN   9.0   0.0
```

Please post actual code and some test data that shows the problem you're asking about.

Comment: Ah, I must have done something wrong. I'll check the code again.Thank you.

Comment: I you feel this answers your question, you could click the checkmark to accept the answer. If you feel your question was made in error, you can close / delete it. Or, if you realise what you did different and you want to change your question, you can edit it.